# What was the first movie to show "Google" on-screen?

Tags: first-appearance

Google was founded in 1998. So what was the first movie to show "Google" on-screen?

Comment: I remember seeing it in Final Destination 2(2003), but it is very much possible that an earlier movie may have shown Google. Since I saw it on TV, I am/will be unable to provide any screenshots.

Comment: Does a parody/fake similar name of google count? Is this question specifically and exactly “google” on screen, or the first acknowledgment of googled existence is enough?

Comment: How about "Googol"? (The word the brand evokes.) Here's Carl Sagan describing it in the 1980s: https://youtu.be/0lFQOmb6mVs

Comment: I wonder if [Alta Vista](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltaVista) made it to the big screen first. I'd been using AV maybe 5 years before Google really started to displace it, but the web itself was still only really catering to 'pro' users at that point, it hadn't hit the big time.

Comment: Define **On-screen**. is it on the screen we watch or is it on a physical screen in the movie/show?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe not quite what you're looking for, since this isn't a movie and Google itself wasn't shown on screen, but the first known use of the verb "to google" in pop culture media was in an episode of Buffy the Vampire Slayer from 2002.

Sources:

https://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2014/06/the-first-use-of-the-verb-to-google-on-television-buffy-the-vampire-slayer/373599/

[image: Willow asks "Have you googled her yet?"]